# Alguien hizo una edición dañina de mi pregunta ¿A quien le pido un rollback?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, ediciones

Alguien editó [mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1973/error-the-type-java-lang-integer-should-be-defined-by-model-annotation) causando problemas.

Hice el regreso de los cambios a mano, pero ¿Cómo puedo solicitar que se cancele esa edición? y sobre todo ¿Cómo puedo evitar que alguien más haga la misma edición?

### Contexto

Minutos antes había rechazado que pusieran la etiqueta *Java*, debido a que la implementación de la etiqueta es la siguiente:

```java
@Property(name = "movimientos", type = Integer.class)
```

Es correcto desde el punto de vista de *Java*, pues recibe objetos:

```java
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(value = {})
public @interface Property {

    public String name();

    public Class<?> type();

    public boolean array() default false;
}
```

... por lo que acepta *Objetos*.

El problema reside estrictamente en *Dukescript* por lo que alguien con conocimientos básicos de *Java* no lo puede resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta de Carlos Muñoz es muy buena, sólo quiero añadir que sí hay mecanismos para tratar con ediciones dañinas pero están reservados para casos extremos, cosa que el que nos ocupa no es:

- Un moderador puede bloquear una pregunta. Pero eso no sólo impide las ediciones, también la emisión de votos y la adición de nuevas preguntas y comentarios. La pregunta y todo su contenido asociado quedan "congelados".
- Si un usuario realiza muchas ediciones que se consideran dañinas, un moderador puede ponerse en contacto con él y si es necesario suspender su cuenta (para ello es útil que alguna de sus acciones sea reportada).

Pero, repito, este caso en concreto entra dentro de lo que es el funcionamiento normal del sitio.

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Cómo puedo solicitar que se cancele esa edición?

No se puede ya es parte del historial, lo cual no es malo. Simplemente refleja el hecho que se hizo una edición y luego se revertió. Eso también puede ayudar a que si se ve la reversión en el historial no se trate de hacer el mismo cambio sabiendo que ya fue revertido.

> ¿Cómo puedo evitar que alguien más haga la misma edición?

No se puede ya que el espíritu del sitio es que cualquiera con la reputación suficiente puede editar las preguntas. Esto es *by-design*.

Después de responder a estas dos preguntas quisiera aportar lo sgte:

La etiqueta [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) en esta pregunta **Sí es relevante** ya que se trata del **lenguaje de programación** en el que está escrito el código de la pregunta. [*DukeScript*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dukescript) es una plataforma similar a [*Apache Cordova*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-cordova) o [*Xamarin*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin) que utilizan *JavaScript* o *C#* respectivamente y si ves las preguntas con esas etiquetas en el sitio en inglés (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-cordova y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin) verás que hay tanto preguntas etiquetadas con ambas como con solo la correspondiente a la plataforma sin el lenguaje de programación.

Independientemente si el error es en algún componente de DukeScript, etiquetar la pregunta como [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tiene varias ventajas.

- Ayuda a la coloración de sintaxis. El syntax highlighter de Stack Overflow utiliza las etiquetas para ayudar a determinar en que lenguaje de programación esta escrito el código ([What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) y [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting))
- Etiquetas favoritas e ignoradas y filtros. Suponiendo por ejemplo que alguien no le interesa ver jamás preguntas sobre java y la coloca como etiqueta ignorada, si esta pregunta solo esta etiquetada como [dukescript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dukescript) le seguirá saliendo en la página de inicio. De la misma manera alguien que quiere ver todas las preguntas relacionadas con java en un filtro por ejemplo no encontrará esta pregunta al realizar la búsqueda.

Las etiquetas se usan en conjunto (hasta 5 etiquetas), por eso es buena idea siempre usar una para definir el lenguaje de programación. Incluir la etiqueta java **no significa para nada que se trata de una pregunta general de Java**, sino que mas bien complementa la pregunta con el lenguaje de programación utilizado.

En conclusión me parece que la edición es buena. **Definitivamente no es destructiva**. Te recomendaría volver a hacer rollback a la versión editada o agregarle tu mismo la etiqueta.

Comment: He movido los comentarios al chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33819/discussion-on-answer-by-carlos-munoz-alguien-hizo-una-edicion-danina-de-mi-pregu . Por favor, no uséis el sistema de comentarios para discusiones largas.

Comment: Hola @Konamiman, disculpa ¿a cuál chat?

Comment: Se ha creado una sala de chat específica, he editado el comentario original con el enlace.